# What type of regression analysis is best to model the relationship between self-efficacy and activity level over three time points?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

I am conducting an orthopedic study to predict improvements in activity level (dependent variable) based on a type of self-efficacy scale (the independent variable). There are, however, other predictors that I wish to include in the model. All scales are continuous.

Since this study will be conducted longitudinally - in other words, I wish to collect this scale data from patients at three different time points (baseline, 3-months, and 6-months) - I am wondering what type of regression analysis is best.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a mixed model, aka multi-level model or hierarchical linear model. You will need to account for the dependence in the data

Answer (score 1):

A simple and very popular approach is to use mixed models to consider the dependence in longitudinal data. Of simple, I mean there are a few free softwares that you can use to fit your model. If your response variable is discrete, you may apply generalized linear mixed models. Then, you can use R packages "lmer", for likelihood based analysis, or "INLA", for Bayesian analysis.